# Implementing medium-style "Login with google" using Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin

I would like to use Firebase authentication (JS SDK) to allow my users to see the "Medium-style" login with Google in the top-right:

[image]

I cannot find anything in the documentation related to this flow. Is this only available to the generic ["Sign in with Google" SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)? I don't want to have two authentication dependencies if possible.